# addChildWindow:ordered: methods behaves strangely in snow leopard machine

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nswindow, childwindow

I have a main window from which I am presenting a sub window as the child of the main window. When I close the main window and then restore it from dock, both windows will come again. After that when I try to close my child window, main window is also getting closed. And when I restore it from dock, I see that close button of child window is disabled. This happens only in snow leopard. And it works fine in Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed - simply in the child window delegate:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[self.window parentWindow] removeChildWindow:self.window];
}
```